# PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver in spring-projects/spring-data-commons

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I use spring and in my context I created bean:

```
<bean id="pageableResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
        <constructor-arg ref="sortResolver" />
        <property name="oneIndexedParameters" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Also I use backbone framework as frontend.

When I generate request with page=1&size=10 when oneIndexedParameters is true then I expect to receive first page with 10 records. In current configuration I receive first page with nine records. It is right? How I can configure PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver to decrement only pageNumber, but not pageSize?

Answer (score 1):

I filed and fixed [DATACMNS-761](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-761) for you.